# Type Cast a string to char in c++

Tags: c++

I have a string `String s = "B"`

I want to convert it to `char cs = 'B'`

How can I do?

Comment: You can at least try [Google](http://www.google.co.in/search?&rls=en&q=TypeCast+a+string+to+char+in+c%2B%2B&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) first.

Comment: This has nothing to do with casting, tag removed.

Comment: Get the corresponding null terminated C style character array by c_str method. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retrieve characters from `string` by index

```
std::string s = "B"; // It has at least one character

char cs = s[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

A `std::string` can be accessed just like an array to access the single characters:

```
char cs = s[0];
```

But be careful, just like an array you can use it with an index out of bounds!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot *cast* a `string` to a `char`. Nor can you really *convert* it either. By definition a string contains zero or more `char`s, so what you want to do is unclear at best!

For example, what would you expect if you had `String s = "BC"`? `'B'`? `'C'`? `4` (the overflowed sum of `'B'` and `'C'`)? Something else?

---

If instead you want to get the first character in the string, you can access it as you would an array by doing:

```
char cs = s[0];
```

Note you should do some kind of bounds checking first to make sure there is at least one character in the string.

Answer (score 1):

The following will get the first character of `s` (or 0 if the string is empty):

```
std::string s = ...;
char cs = 0;
if (!s.empty()) {
  cs = s[0];
}
```