# String to char - C++

Tags: c++, string, char, int

How can I convert a string to char?

I already Googled and I didn't find the answer to the situation I'm in. Really, I'm trying to convert an int to a char but my compiler doesn't support the to_string function so I decided to convert to from int to string then string to char.

I'm using a char[ ][ ] so I can store integers and chars.

```
stringstream ss;
ss << j; // j is the integer
string s(ss.str());
ascii_text[1][i] = (char)s;
```

EDIT:

I'm working with ASCII chars.

This is what I'm trying to do.
int a = 10; -> string s = "10"; -> char c = '10';

I'll be happy if I found a way to convert int to char directly.

Comment: Did you think this through?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655202/how-to-convert-integer-to-string-in-c

Comment: @Rapptz Yes. Why do you ask?

Comment: How do you imagine the result to look like? A string consists of several `char`s. Which of those do you want?

Comment: If the earlier comments are too subtle, you're asking "How do I convert a collection of characters into a single character?"  That doesn't have a well-defined meaning.

Comment: int a = 10; -> string s = "10"; -> char c = '10';

Comment: I'm working with ASCII chars so...

Comment: `'10'` is 2 characters, not one.

Comment: @Rapptz Oh I didn't see that. My bad.

Comment: @AdegokeA Do you still have a question?

Comment: @DrewDormann Yeah, I still don't know how I can convert from int to char.

Comment: By the way, casting like that was the subject of a question asked earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15609575/type-cast-a-string-to-char-in-c

Comment: @AdegokeA edit your question so it clearly reflects *the question you have*

Comment: It looks like you still don't understand exactly why `char c = '10'` is nonsense.  A `char` is a data type designed to hold **one character**.  You're trying to pour two cans of Diet Coke into an empty Diet Coke can.  There's a mess on the floor now.

Comment: I do. But how can I store integers and chars in the same 2D array?

Comment: @AdegokeA Given your new question in the comments, I recommend that you step back and analyze what the bigger problem is that you're trying to solve.  It seems like what you're really trying to do is store an `int` as an array of ASCII characters, but I'm not sure.  Each revised question has implied that you're trying to build on incorrect assumptions.  Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you correctly, then all you want to do is get from an integer digit (0-9) to an ascii digit ('0'-'9')? In that case, `char(j)+'0'` will do.

Comment: Have to add tens places too http://stackoverflow.com/a/7022827/195488 , if going to int

Comment: @Cubic I already tried that and I got ASCII chars, like 20 would give be space instead of '20'.

Comment: @AdegokeA That's because there's no character for the number 20. If you want a string, then you just take the string you already got.

Comment: I'm using a char[][] so I can store integers and chars. See my problem?

Comment: @AdegokeA No, I don't. I don't know what you're trying to do, but I think you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I am. I didn't have to use a 2D array. Thanks though. :)

Answer (score 3):

> How can I convert a string to char?

Okay. If you mean `char*`, then the `std::string` class has a `c_str()` method:

```
std::string myString = "hello";
const char* myStr = myString.c_str();
```

A `char` has a size of 1 byte, so you can't fit any string in it, unless that string has a length of 1. You *can* however get the char at a certain position in a string:

```
std::string str = "hi bro";
char c = str[0]; // This will be equal to 'h'
```

Comment: `std::string::c_str` returns a `const char*`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just do

```
int j = 3;
char ch;
stringstream ss;
ss << j;
ss >> ch;
```

Comment: If string is "61", it only give '6' back.

Comment: There is no string in my code.  He is trying to convert an int, there is no reason for him to use a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the c_str() method to get an array of chars from string.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/